# AngularJS ng-repeat setting attributes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to get rid of a bunch of repeating divs using ng-repeat.

```
  <!-- I have 21 of these -->
  <div class="table-row">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
     <label>Chloride</label>
     <input type="range" min="700" max="1200" ng-model="chlorideSlider"/>
     <input type="text" class="val" ng-model="chloride"/>
  </div>

  <!-- I'd like to use ng-repeat to create them -->
  <div class="table-row" ng-repeat="item in sliderItems.items">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
     <label>{{ item.label }}</label>
     <input type="range" min="item.min" max="item.max" ng-model="item.slider"/>
     <input type="text" class="val" ng-model="item.model"/>
  </div>
```

This is the data:

```
  $scope.sliderItems = { 'items' : [
     {'label' : 'WBC', 'min' : 0, 'max' : 600,  'slider' : $scope.wbc, 'model' : $scope.wbc, 'tr' : 'wbc_tr' },
     {'label' : 'Respiration', 'min' : 0, 'max' : 60,  'slider' : $scope.resp, 'model' : $scope.resp, 'tr' : 'wbc_tr' }
  ]};
```

min and max don't work at all. The models show the correct values until they change and I get an attempt to change read only value error.

Comment: What you want to do? Its not clear.. :(

Comment: I'd like to do things like in the second div. However, that's not working as noted above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Min and Max need to be wrapped in `{{ }}` because they are not angular directives and therefore do not evaluate the expression. So it would become:

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="item in sliderItems.items">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
     <label>{{ item.label }}</label>
     <input type="range" min="{{item.min}}" max="{{item.max}}" ng-model="item.slider"/>
     <input type="text" class="val" ng-model="item.model"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: That works now for min max. However, the value is set for the model but then never updates when the model does or when you move the slider on the range.

Comment: You might want to look into creating a custom directive for that sort of thing. Otherwise, is there a "onSliderChange" type event you can hook into to get the new value?

Comment: What confuses me is <input type="text" class="val" ng-model="wbc"/> works and <input type="text" class="val" ng-model="item.model"/> only works on init but then doesn't update. Thanks

Comment: What do you expect to see in the textbox?

Comment: If you're expecting to see the value of the slider in the textbox, then you'll need to assign the same model to both. Either `ng-model="item.slider"` or `ng-model="item.model"`

Comment: The models are synced in the controller. The values are non int ranges so there's a conversion. on update of the slider the controller does $scope.wbc = $scope.sliderWbc / 10 for example.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the way the scope is being handled in each repeat block. I would make the slider and the textbox a directive which would give you an isolated scope. This may fix your problem as well as being a bit of a more reuseable pattern

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="item in sliderItems.items">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
     <label>{{ item.label }}</label>
     <input type="range" min="{{item.min}}" max="{{item.max}}" ng-model="item.slider"/>
     <input type="text" class="val" ng-model="item.model"/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a model that way. Try this instead:

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="item in sliderItems.items">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
 <label>{{ item.label }}</label>
 <input type="range" min="{{item.min}}" max="{{item.max}}" ng-change="setSlider($index)"/>
 <input type="text" class="val" ng-change="setModel($index)"/>
</div>
```

Inside of your controller you will need functions similar to these:

```
$scope.setSlider = function(selectedSlider){
    $scope.mySlider = items[selectedSlider].slider;
}

$scope.setModel = function(selectedModel){
    $scope.myModel = items[selectedModel].model;
}
```

Comment: it wouldn't work with `setModel({{item.model}})` - you need to remove the `{{ }}` from the `item.model`.

Comment: Ew... good point... got a little over-zealous with them. Edited that out. Thanks.

Comment: This give me this error: Expression 'setSlider(item.slider)' is non-assignable. Element: http://bit.ly/1bRXaEb

Comment: In that case, pass the index value and use that to choose which property in your object collection you need to select. Example edited.